# How to add google+ signin and linked in sign in button in Titanium alloy project

Tags: titanium, google-plus, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am working on an app for iphone and android. I want to allow user to login using google plus and linked as well. I have the GoogleAuth.js and m using it but i want to use google's signin button .

What i have done is i downloaded assets from google's branding page and used them in TSS. But there is an Google+ iOS module on Google's developer website. **Haven't found more than the rest api for LinkedIn. It can wait though.**

```
Alloy view
    <Alloy>
        <Window class="container" title="Log In">
            <TextField id = "txtUsername" hintText = "Username"/>
            <TextField id = "txtPassword" hintText = "Password" passwordMask = "true"/>
            <Button id = "btnEmailLogin" title = "Login" onClick = "loginWithEmail"/>
            <Label id = "lblOrText"  text = "OR"></Label>
            <LoginButton id = "btnFacebookLogin" ns = "Alloy.Globals.Facebook"/>
            <Button id = "btnGoogleLogin" onClick = "loginWithGoogle" />
        </Window>
    </Alloy>
```

TSS :

```
".container": {
    backgroundColor:"white"
},
"#txtUsername":{
    top:40,
    width:"90%",
    left:"5%",
    height:32,
    borderStyle:Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    color:"black",
    font:{fontFamily:"Helvetica",fontSize:15}
},
"#txtPassword":{
    top:80,
    left:"5%",
    width:"90%",
    height:32,
    borderStyle:Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    color:"black",
    font:{fontFamily:"Helvetica",fontSize:15}   
},
"#btnEmailLogin":{
    top:120,
    left:"20%",
    width:"60%",
    height:44,
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    color:"black",
     backgroundGradient: {
        type: 'linear',
        startPoint: { x: '0%', y: '0%' },
        endPoint: { x: '0%', y: '100%' },
        colors: [ { color: '#5FDAFC', offset: 0.25 }, { color: '#06ADDB', offset: 1.0 } ],
    }
},
"#lblOrText":{
    top:170,
    width:"auto"
},
"#btnFacebookLogin":{
    top:200,

},
"#btnGoogleLogin":{
    backgroundImage:"images/Red-signin-Long-base-44dp.png",
    width:246,
    height:44,
    top:250
}
```

CONTROLLER :

```
/* CODE for Fb login before this */

var GoogleAuth = Alloy.Globals.GoogleAuth;
var googleAuth = new GoogleAuth({
    clientId : '1XXXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    clientSecret : 'secretsecretsecret',
    propertyName : 'profile',
    scope : ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login']
});

function loginWithGoogle(){
    googleAuth.authorize();
}
```

Comment: You should provide some code example showing what you implemented and where you are stuck.

Comment: hey @daniula here's the code.